# synchronized object set to null

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have two threads `Thread1` and `Thread2`

```
//Within Thread1     
synchronized(obj1)  
{  
    obj1 = null;  
}  

//Within Thread2  
synchronized(obj1)  
{  
    do something  
}
```

If jvm first executes thread1 and sets obj1 to null, then will thread2 see that change immediately or will it take time and jvm could still run the thread2 synchronized block since obj1 is not yet null?

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk He couldn't try himself, any type of concurrency related issue is non deterministic.  These types of comments are extremely frustrating when the context isn't known.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will almost certainly break the synchronization abstraction -- I wouldn't be confident that `thread2` will see the change immediately.  You should never change the reference of the object you're synchronizing on, much less set it to `null`, which will cause a `NullPointerException` on any further attempts to synchronize on it.

Answer (score 16):

First let me emphasise that modifying a variable that is used for synchronization is a **terribly bad thing**. `obj1` should be `final` and never be touched if it is used as a monitor.

That being said, back to your question:

If JVM first executes Thread1, it synchronizes on `obj1`, sets it to `null` and the thread exits. The second thread wants to synchronize on `obj1`, `NullPointerException` will be thrown. Because the modification of `obj1` was made in synchronized block, it is guaranteed that Thread2 will see updated value (so: `NullPointerException` is guaranteed).

If Thread1 is interrupted after obtaining the lock on `obj1` but before clearing the reference, Thread2 will lock on `obj1` and wait until Thread1 finished. Then it will successfully enter the monitor because the object previously referenced by `obj1` still exists.

Comment: since obj1 is being used in the synchronized condition and not in the synchronized block, is it not possible that both the threads try to synchronize at the same time and thread1 enters first and thread2 caches the value of obj1. when thread1 exits thread2 takes the value of obj1 from the cache and enters the synchronized block and sees the change within the synchronized block

Comment: @Tomsaz I didn't get this statement of yours _If Thread1 is interrupted after obtaining the lock on obj1 but before clearing the reference, Thread2 will lock on obj1 and wait until Thread1 finished_ Now first of all we interrupts thread only when they are blocked and anyway if they are not blocked the interrupting them has no effect, right? Basically I never see a case where thread1 will relinquish the lock without completeing the synchronized block or without wait() getting called on that lock itself. IOW, when and why would thread2 get the lock but would still wait for thread1 to finish.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` is *not* guaranteed. Performing a write in a `synchronized` block only guarantees visibility for threads subsequently entering a `synchronized` block for the same object, but not for the read happening *before* entering the `synchronized` block. So without other synchronization, the second thread may throw a `NullPointerException` or not, that’s unpredictable. Only when it dereferences the variable again within the `synchronized` block, the `NullPointerException` is guaranteed.

Answer (score 5):

`synchronized` synchronizes on the object, and not the reference. By setting `obj1` (a reference) to null, thread2 can't synchronize on the object formerly pointed to by `obj1`, you'll get a `NullPointerException` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix is to make the object a simple array of 1 element and refer to the array for synchronization, e.g.,

Object[] obj1 = {null};

The element can be null without impacting the existence of the array.  Granted, this still breaks the "rule" of not using the object itself in synchronization, but unless your code complicates matters elsewhere, this quick fix should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The change is immediate. When Thread 1 "owns" the lock, it can change the value of obj1 at will. Thread 2 has to wait until Thread 1 releases the lock. It will definitely see obj1 == null