# Java synchronized multithreading example

Tags: java, multithreading

Where do I need to place the keyword `synchronized` if I want to prevent that the two threads are manipulating `tab` simultaneously?

`Mainclass` owns the variable `tab` it's methods `f1,f2,f3` are manipulating `tab`. `f2,f2` are called by the main method in a loop, and `f3` is called by a thread, in `x` milliseconds after a event occurs in the main method.

main method:

```
main() {
    Mainclass mainclass = new Mainclass(); // class containing variable tab
    while (condition) {
        mainclass.f1(); // manipulating tab
        mainclass.f2(); // manipulating tab
        if (eventOccured) {
            mainclass.startThread(x); 
            // thread calls f3() after x milliseconds whitch is manipulating tab
        }
    }
}
```

IMainclass:

```
public class Mainclass {
    public void f1(){...}  // manipulating tab
    public void f2(){...}  // manipulating tab
    public void f3(){...}  // manipulating tab
    public final TabObject[][] tab;
}
```

Can I synchronize `tab`, or do I have to synchronize `f1,f2,f3`, should I use a synchronized block like `synchronized (tab) {...}` or syncronize the whole mehtods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to synchronize `f1`, `f2` and `f3`. However, this will imply that at any moment, at most one of these methods can run. This can have some performance issues if those methods are performing some heavy computations not related to `tab`.

For example, assume the following :

```
public void f1() {

    /*
       Do some I/O, e.g. read in/write very large files (typically very slow)
    */

    synchronized(tab) {
        // Than manipulate "tab"
    }
}
```

In this case it is clearly better to have a synchronized block around the tab manipulations instead of synchronizing the whole method. Doing so, `f1`, `f2` and `f3` can run at the same time to do some slow I/O operations and only synchronize upon manipulating `tab`, possibly resulting in a better performance.

Comment: @svasa Found this topic, pretty well explaining why you should not do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195054/synchronized-object-set-to-null

Comment: @svasa Note that in this case `tab` is declared as `final` so one won't be able to set it to null afterwards.

Comment: I know why I should not do that, but if I use some getter method to reset my "tab" like tab = getValues(); This could well be from a third party jar and for some reason getValues() returned null. Before that, if tab is declared final - how can it be "manipulated"?

Comment: Knowing that it could possibly return `null` you should explicitly have checked it before assigning it. Ps: if you do `tab = ...` it's not a getter but a setter for tab.

Comment: Ok. I mean setting tab value using a getter.

Comment: @svasa i don't think it's a good practice to have a getter with side effects, feel free to correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: You can manipulate the content, but not the variable itself, if it is declared as final. You can't change the pointer (`tab = new ...()` or `= null`), but you can do sth like that: `tab[1][0] = 5`

Answer (score 2):

```
synchronized void A(){
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void A(){
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but using `this` as lock [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/442601/1094430).

Without knowing the details of the methods, you can just use the `synchronized (tab) {...}` block as you said, but I'd use it only to wrap lines that are actually reading/writing the `tab` var instead of having it for the whole method.

If you want to make things cleaner you can even add

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

and use `synchronized (lock) {...}` instead on synchronizing to `tab` (which is `public`, meaning that another class may synchronize to it leading to deadlock).

Comment: The Object `lock` would just be as marking that a critical operation is running right now, or?

Comment: In a sense. Basically, each *Java* object has an implicit lock used for synchronization (that's why a `synchronized` method is like a `synchronized(this)` block), but using a `private Object` instead of `this` allows your code to be more "safe". I'm not really sure if that's what you asked, so if I misunderstood your question please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a monitor object like `private Object monitor = new Object();` and call the code manipulating tab inside a synchronized block like

You can place this synchronized block inside your methods f1,f2,f3 like :

```
public void f1()
{

   synchronized(monitor)
   { 
     //code to manipulate tab
   }
}
```