# java concurrency synchronized on map value

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code, I am confused about what would happen when 2 threads compete the lock for `map.get(k)`. When thread A wins, it makes `map.get(k)` null and the second thread would get a `synchronized(null)`? Or would it be both threads see it as `synchronized(v)` even though the first thread changes it to null but during which thread B still sees it as `v`?

```
synchronized(map.get(k)) {
   map.get(k).notify();
   map.remove(k);
}
```

The question is a similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195054/synchronized-object-set-to-null), except lock object is value of a map.

**UPDATE**:
compared the discussion in this post and that in the above link, is it true that

```
synchronized(v) {
    v.notify();
    v = null;
}
```

would cause the 2nd thread `synchronized(null)`. But for the `synchronized(map.get(k))`, the 2nd thread would have `synchronized(v)`???

**UPDATE**:
To answer @Holger's question, the main difference between this post and the other one is:

```
final V v = new V();
synchonized(map.get(k)) {
    map.get(k).notify();
    map.remove(k);
}
```

Comment: that would also throw a nullpoint exception because you cant call notify() on null

Comment: @PhilippSander for the first thread it would work. Because when calling notify, the value has not yet been removed

Comment: @Lino What if the method called before having the K key
It will throw another NullPointerException before entering the if statement

Comment: @PhilippSander for the second thread, which statement throws NPE?　synchronized or notify?

Comment: @Tiina `notify()`, since it's being called on the (now removed) result of `get(k)`.

Comment: @Kayaman does 2nd thread see `synchronized(v)`? why not `synchronized(null)` as it is removed?

Comment: @Tiina that would be a race condition, so you can get different results based on timing. However the original question makes more sense if we assume that threads arrive at the same time (in which case there would be no NPE).

Comment: I don’t get your question. The answer to the question you’ve linked, does already tell you that synchronizing on a mutable variable is completely broken, so what do you expect from exchanging the mutable variable with a mutable map, which adds even more possible race conditions?

Comment: @Holger I updated the question.

Comment: And why do you think, adding the entirely unrelated statement `final V v = new V();` clarifies anything? Not that it matters, as I didn't even asked about the difference; my previous comment already said what the difference is “*exchanging the mutable variable with a mutable map, which adds even more possible race conditions*”. I asked why you expect this difference to help in any way with code that is already known to be broken.

Comment: @Holger the object being monitored is not modified, and that is exactly what answers in the post suggest: do not modify being monitored object and use `final` when necessary.

Comment: Don't mix up variables and objects. The answer clearly says, “*You should never change the reference of the object you're synchronizing on*”, as you must synchronize *on the same object*, which has nothing to do with modifications to the object. Making the reference variable `final` is one way to ensure that it always points to the same object. Replacing the variable access with an expression that can return a different object on each evaluation (as you are querying a `Map` which you also modify), is the exact opposite of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second thread won't "request" a lock on `thread.get(k)`, both threads will request a lock on the result of `map.get(k)` **before** the first one starts executing. So the code is roughly similar to:

```
Object val = map.get(k);
val.notify();
```

So, when the thread that obtained the lock finishes executing, the second thread will still have a reference to `Object val`, even if `map[k]` doesn't point to it anymore (or points to `null`)

---

**EDIT**: (following many useful comments)

It seems that the lock on `map.get(k)` is being acquired to ensure that the processing is done only once (`map.remove(k)` is called after processing). While it's true that 2 threads that compete for the lock on `val` won't run into `null.notify()`, the safety of this code is not guaranteed **as the second thread may call `synchronized(map.get(k))` after the first one has exited the synchronized block**.

To ensure that the `k` is processed atomically, a safer approach may be needed. **One** way to do this is to use a concurrent hash map, like below:

```
map.computeIfPresent(k, (key, value) -> {
    //process the value here
    //key is k
    //value is the value to which k is mapped.

    return null; //return null to remove the value after processing.
});
```

Please note that `map` in the preceding example is an instance of `ConcurrentHashMap`. This will ensure that the value is processed once (`computeIfPresent` runs atomically).

To quote `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` doc comments:

> If the value for the specified key is present, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value. The entire method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this map.

Comment: @Lino Absolutely. Thanks!!

Comment: @Tiina No, running `v = null;` won't affect the other thread at all. `v` (or `val` in this answer) is a method-local variable and won't change anything for other threads.

Comment: @ernest_k how can you predict what the second thread will have, when both threads execute the first `map.get(k)` without any synchronization? The evaluation of `map.get(k)` is part of the what the threads do, not happening “before the first one starts executing”. The second thread *may* see the value the map had before the removal, but it may also see the `null` reference or break in an entirely different way due to seeing an inconsistent state of the map, as it doesn’t look like the OP is using a thread safe map.

Comment: @Holger That's a valid point, but the question was specific about one thing: `what would happen when 2 threads compete the lock for map.get(k). When thread A wins...`, which clearly supposes that the lock is attempted on the map value, i.e., beyond the null pointer access. Threads won't "compete" for the lock after one had gotten it and modified the map, the second one would simply crash. So the premise is slightly different.

Comment: @ernest_k but you have identified the flaw in that premise yourself right in your answer: “*second thread won't ’request’ a lock on `thread.get(k)`, both threads will request a lock on the result of `map.get(k)`*”, but the result of `map.get(k)` is unpredictable. Your answer does not indicate that the assumption that thread two reads a non-`null` value stems from taking the OP’s flawed premise for granted, misguiding the OP into thinking that this was a working solution while it is actually broken.

Comment: @Holger I've reread the question following your observations and I find that this answer was written for a much simpler version of the question. I'll edit the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Tiina Please check the edited answer, there have been important observations made in above comments.

Comment: "2 threads that compete for the lock on val won't run into null.notify" why the 2nd thread does not get null.notify?

Comment: @Tiina Because for them to compete, they must call `.notify()` on the same object (i.e., before either of them starts running). And that was the point of the edit, please use a more reliable way running atomically.

Answer (score 3):

What would happen is that you would lock on the value *currently* in the hashmap entry for key `k`.

Problem #1 - if the `map.get(k)` call returns `null`, then you would get an NPE.

Problem #2 - since you are not locking on `map`:

- you are likely to get race conditions with other threads; e.g. if some other thread does a `map.put(k, v)` with a different `v` to the one you are locking, and
- the `map.remove(k)` may result in memory anomalies leading (potentially) to corruption of the map data structure.

It is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve by synchronizing on `map.get(k)` (rather than `map`).  But whatever it is, this code is not thread-safe.

---

Re your update: Yes that is true ... assuming that other thread is synchronizing on the value of the same variable `v`.  Note that you *always* synchronize on an object, so when you do `synchronized(v)`, that means "take the current value of `v` and synchroize on that object".